# Open Cart - Passing Custom Variable

Tags: php, opencart

Custom Controller Variables (Payment module) MVC-L model

I'm adding in a variable to set an Iframe URL in a custom payment module.
I've added into the controller.php but cannot access in payment.tpl

Any ideas ?

In OpenCart v1.5.6 i have inserted an iframe as below. The URL should be derived from the Controller section.

```
     <div class="content" id="payment">  <table class="form">
        <tr>
          <td>
          <iframe name="netbanx" src="<?php echo $amped; ?>" style="width:900px; height:550px;"></iframe>
</td>
        </tr>   </table> </div>
```

from my controller.php file

```
$amped = $this->full_uri( $token, $action, $endpoint );
```

Comment: You need to be more specific, so anyone can answer that question. please post a code snippet when your problem is, and tell us  what you've tried

Comment: In OpenCart v1.5.6 i have inserted an iframe as below. The URL should be derived from the Controller section.

Answer (score 0):

In Your controller it is not

```php
$amped = $this->full_uri( $token, $action, $endpoint );
```

**but**

```php
$this->data['amped'] = $this->full_uri($token, $action, $endpoint);
```

The variable `$this->data` (which is of type `array`) is used as variables holder that is then used to assign values into it's respective variables in the template.